# How to get a different Time value in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get a different time value. For example, I don't want the current time but the time of 6:52 am. I also want to add a various number of minutes and seconds to that time (but I'll figure that part out :)). 
I thought this code would give me the desired time but it's not working:

```
import time

leave_time = time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=6, tm_min=52,
                 tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=335, tm_isdst=-1)
print ("My leave time is %r") %leave_time
```

Also, I don't need the date. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module instead:

```
import datetime

leave_time = datetime.time(6, 52)
print("My leave time is {}".format(leave_time))  # My leave time is 06:52:00
```